# Why Samsung Galaxy S10 Plus skin looks odd in Android Studio?

Tags: android-studio, android-emulator, galaxy, samsung-galaxy

I downloaded Samsung Galaxy S10 Plus skin from samsung [official website](https://developer.samsung.com/galaxy-emulator-skin/overview.html#Featured-Devices) and installed it into Android Studio using [their guide](https://developer.samsung.com/galaxy-emulator-skin/guide.html). However, the emulator looks quite different from photos of real Galaxy S10 Plus.

[image: Galaxy S10 Plus emulator]
[image: Real Galaxy S10 Plus]

As you can see there are no round corners, no front camera. Did I miss something or Samsung made a poor quality skin?

Answer (score 0):

It's because you missed the fore_port.png file, or configured it wrongly. Open the layout file with a text editor then edit like this:

```
    portrait {
    background {
        image   device_Port.png
    }
    foreground  {
        mask    fore_port.png
    }
    }
```

Comment: Where can I find the layout file?